# statistical distance in symmetric-key encryption

Tags: symmetric

Prove that for any symmetric-key encrytion scheme $\Pi=(Gen, Enc, Dec)$ with message space $M$ and key space $K$, there exist $m_0, m_1 \in M$ such that $\Delta(Enc(K, m_0), Enc(K, m_1))\ge 1-\frac{|K|}{|M|}$.

I know that $\Delta(X,Y)=\max\limits_{T\subseteq S}(Pr(X\in T)-Pr(Y\in T))$, but I have no idea about the inequation above. I tried to prove by contradiction but failed.